# Reading from file without specific index

Tags: c#

Does anyone know how can I read .txt file if there is not given specific number how many times to read those lines. For example:
FileName.txt

```
ShopName;Adress;TNumber;  
ItemName;Price;Color;Weight;Size;Rating;  
ItemName;Price;Color;Weight;Size;Rating;  
ItemName;Price;Color;Weight;Size;Rating;  
ItemName;Price;Color;Weight;Size;Rating;  
ShopName;Adress;TNumber;  
ItemName;Price;Color;Weight;Size;Rating;  
ItemName;Price;Color;Weight;Size;Rating;  
ShopName;Adress;TNumber;   
ItemName;Price;Color;Weight;Size;Rating;  
ItemName;Price;Color;Weight;Size;Rating;  
ItemName;Price;Color;Weight;Size;Rating;
```

ShopName, Adress, TNumber go to one class Shop and that class(Shop.cs) stores data from another class Item.cs

Comment: *how many times to read that line* Which line?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: No idea what you're asking.

Comment: I need a loop to read this kind of txt

Comment: Then use a loop? `string line; while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null) { // do stuff }`?

Comment: In your deleted comment you said something about needing the index? You could increment a value of an integer inside your read loop (e.g. `++currentLine;`). If you need something different, you might want to give us a bit more info than just your file.

Comment: Did you give a try at google : "c# read file" ?

Comment: Ok, I see your point I will try to do something :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only chance to check the line-type is  to count the semicolons (Or split and cout the result-array-length).

```
public static void Main()
{
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Temp\Test.txt");
    List<Shop> shops = new List<Shop>();
    Shop shop = null;
    while(!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        string line = sr.ReadLine().Trim().TrimEnd(';');

        string[] split = line.Split(';');

        if (split.Count() == 3)
        {
            if (shop != null)
                shops.Add(shop);

            shop = new Shop()
            {
                Name = split[0],
                Adr = split[1],
                TNumber = split[2],
            };
        }
        else
        {
            Item item = new Item()
            {
                Name = split[0],
                Price = split[1],
                Color = split[2],
                Weight = split[3],
                Size = split[4],
                Rating = split[5]
            };
            shop.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
    if (shop != null)
        shops.Add(shop);

    foreach (Shop s in shops)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s.Name + ", " + s.Adr + ", " + s.TNumber);
        foreach (Item i in s.Items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("   " + i.Name + ", " + i.Price);
        }
    }
}

public class Shop
{
    public Shop() { this.Items = new List<Item>(); }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Adr { get; set; }
    public string TNumber { get; set; }

    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public string Weight { get; set; }
    public string Size { get; set; }
    public string Rating { get; set; }
}
```